# Do lightning apps support community?

Tags: community, lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

As an internal user we can display our lightning app from the following url:
`https://ap1.lightning.force.com/[namespace]/[app_name].app`

Now we would like to allow owr community users to access the same lightning app. We tried the following url as an community user:
`https://[mydomain].ap1.force.com/[communityname]/[namespace]/[app_name].app`

But were prompted with an error message: `"Page Not Found: /aura"`

So how can we allow our community users to access our lightning apps?

Answer (score 2):

Internal use by Salesforce so far only - not tested or formally supported as part of the Lightning Components beta. We're working on this for GA.

With that said I was able to use a newly created Lightning Components .app with no difficulties using an authenticated user - have not tried a guest user yet - in a developer edition org with the url of the form that you supplied above.

I have repro'ed the Page Not Found: /aura in my DE org using the guest user and have thus far been unable to work around this. Discussed it with the architect for Communities and he did not believe this would currently work because of the security model in place has not been made Lightning savvy yet.

Comment: Can you clarify your second paragraph?  Are you saying you were able to access a lightning .app with a(n authenticated) community user?  Leaving aside the guest user for now, I cannot even access a Lightning app when logged in as a user with the "Customer Community Login User" profile; I've tried every variation of URLs I can think of.  Can you give an example URL?